# Any way to remove docker container and image automatically even after unsuccessful build?

Tags: docker

I'm practicing Dockerfile to make my own image, but I'm not skilled in these, so many times build error occur. Whenever build error occur, unsuccessful container and image remain, and I should remove it manually with complicate ID.

I know when build successfully work, '-rm=true' field make intermediate container automatically removed. However, what I want is that when docker build fails unsuccessful container and image are removed automatically, so I can rebuild that without hassle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as I know,docker currently support your requirement.you can do it mannuallly in these 2 commands
1.remove all untagged images
docker rmi $(docker images -q -f dangling=true)
2.remove all containers that are not running.
docker rm $(docker ps -a -q)

Comment: It's useful command thanks, but little sorry for that it's not automated

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use `--no-cache` build [option](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/eng-image/dockerfile_best-practices/#build-cache)?

Comment: you mean like this '# docker build --no-cache .'? As I used, no change happened. Did I use wrong?